# 404 Error when copying Orchard CMS

Tags: http-status-code-404, orchardcms

I have one knowingly good site.  It works as expected.  I copied all the files from that one directory to a new directory.  I created a new website with the correct host header and pointed it to the new directory.  When you browse to the new site you get a 404 error.

I have checked the file permissions.  I have even made the two sites share the same app pool.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: I don't have any new logs into App_Data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in /App_Data/Logs you can see the error message.  As it turned out for me, it was because I was trying to run the same "tenant" twice on the same server.